# Bootstrap Navigation stuck on mobile mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

My bootstrap navigation is stuck in mobile mode even on desktop devices - what have I done wrong?

```
<div id="main-menu-container" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-10"><a class="nav-link" title="Home" href="//offline.inspiredchildcare.com.au:3000/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-13"><a class="nav-link" title="About" href="//offline.inspiredchildcare.com.au:3000/about/">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-16"><a class="nav-link" title="Our Centres" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">Our Centres <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></a>
            <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu bg-primary">
                <li class="nav-item" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-22"><a class="nav-link" title="West Pennant Hills" href="//offline.inspiredchildcare.com.au:3000/our-centres/west-pennant-hills/">West Pennant Hills</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-25"><a class="nav-link" title="Glenwood" href="//offline.inspiredchildcare.com.au:3000/our-centres/glenwood/">Glenwood</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-31"><a class="nav-link" title="Blacktown" href="//offline.inspiredchildcare.com.au:3000/our-centres/blacktown/">Blacktown</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-19"><a class="nav-link" title="Contact" href="//offline.inspiredchildcare.com.au:3000/contact/">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Preview: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVbWOx

Comment: You need a `navbar-expand...` class in the navbar

Answer (score 0):

Change `<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" role="navigation">` into this `<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" role="navigation">` and embed `jQuery` into your code

[Here's the codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremiahc/pen/oEJWbb)